# Sending data to rails controller without saving in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, syntax-error

1) I need to get data from the user and process it in one of my controller's function without saving the data from my user in my db. I have this code in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#AEI_submit").on('click', function(event) {
          var aei_login = $("#AEI_login").val();
          var aei_password = $("#AEI_mdp").val();

          $.ajax({

                url: "<%= AEIexport_path(params[:tournament_id]%>",
                dataType: "script",
                data:
                      {
                        aei_login: aei_login,
                        aei_password: aei_password,
                      },

                type: "POST",
                  success: function() {

                    $("#AEI_submit").hide();
                  }

             });
      })
    });

</script>
<% end -%>
```

I wish to send aei_login and aei_password to my backend to process the data but I dont want to save aei_login and aei_password in my db.
a) Is this possible ?
b) If yes how can I use this data from the ajax_call in my rails controller? Can I just call aei_login and aei_password in my controller's method ?
c) The code I posted keeps bringing me `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'` but I can't find the syntax error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is in the url param of the Ajax method. You are missing closing ")".

Comment: Thanks now at least the page is displaying

Comment: do you have an idea for the other questions ?

Comment: The way you are sending data looks good. Change the name 'type' to 'method'. That might help if you are not seeing data being received in the controller.